# create or update many?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here's my code which iterate a list of objects and, for each, check the "unique" field `instrument_name` and update or create the item on a MongoDB:

```
const dateUpdated = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
for (let i = 0; i < instruments.length; i++) {
    let instrument = instruments[i];
    instrument.dateUpdated = dateUpdated;

    let exchangeInstrument;
    try {
        exchangeInstrument = await ExchangeInstrument.updateOne({ instrument_name: instrument.instrument_name }, instrument, { upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
    }
}

// model definition
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

let ExchangeInstrumentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    instrument_name: {
        type: String
    },
    price_decimals: {
        type: String
    },
    quantity_decimals: {
        type: String
    },
    dateUpdated: {
        type: String
    }
}, {
    collection: 'ExchangeInstruments'
})

const ExchangeInstrument = mongoose.model('ExchangeInstrument', ExchangeInstrumentSchema)
export { ExchangeInstrument }
```

It will create N connection on DB, slowing the process.

Can I do it "once"? Such as UpdateOrCreateMany?
And, is there any "key" improvement that I can do on instrument_name field?

Thanks

Comment: You can use bulk update to do it in one query

Comment: @nimrodserok can you show to me a concrete example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bulk update to do something like:

```
const exchangeInstrumentBulk = ExchangeInstrumentModel.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
for (const instrument of instruments) {
    exchangeInstrumentBulk.find({ instrument_name: instrument.instrument_name }).upsert().update({$set:instrument});
}
await exchangeInstrumentBulk.execute()
```

Comment: it says "TypeError: {(intermediate value)}.upsert is not a function". I think a typo around "}).upsert()"

Comment: There were missing `)` before the `.upsert()`

Comment: Is there a way to see which records are created, and which are updated with this bulk operation? Any sort of flag mechanism?

Comment: It returns [BulkWriteResult](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/BulkWriteResult/#mongodb-method-BulkWriteResult)